# header of pdf file

Tags: php

actauuly i want to know that which header are require to convert the data in 
a pdf file.

like for converting a .doc we want

```
header( "Content-disposition: filename=".$filename.".doc");
```

so i want to save my data in pdf

Comment: You realise that this doesn't actually __convert__ your output to a doc or a pdf format, you have to do that yourself. It simply tells the browser to expect a response that is in that format... and even then, your headers aren't complete... you're missing the Content-Type header.

Comment: This is the "serve HTML as .doc to open it in Word" trick gone wild.

Comment: That would be pretty sweet if header converted stuff!

Answer (score 2):

```
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
```

This tells browser that you will be outputting pdf file.

Answer (score 0):

**In PHP there is no option for converting the doc file to pdf file , it only tells the browser in what type we are downloading the file.**